# Open same component parallely in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I had written code for chat box it working for single box, but, suppose, there are multiple product listed in one page and I want to open multiple chat box. Is there anyway to open component like multi-threading.

Comment: What's wrong by just adding the component one more time to the page?

Comment: its not identical, both component will have same values.

Comment: You can open it in multiple tabs in the browser.

Comment: You can write your component in such a way that when creating different instances of it, you can control the differences between instances using props